# How to ignore files when running "npm run build"

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have an app in react where some files are named "exampleFile.nobuild.js"
and when I run the "npm run build" command I would like these ".nobuild" files to be ignored by the build. Is it possible to ignore them?

Comment: What is your compilation step? Can you post your package.json please?

Comment: `npm run build` just calls whatever you write to `package.json` in section `scripts` with key `build`. We need to know what script you are calling.

Comment: If you're using CRA, for example, Webpack will only include things that are accessible from the `index.js` via following `import`s. Are your `.nobuild` files imported anywhere? What makes you think they're included in the build?

Comment: If you are building a package you likely need a `.npmignore` [link](http://npm.github.io/publishing-pkgs-docs/publishing/the-npmignore-file.html)